# Can only run php file in Python by changing to the working directory

Tags: php, python

I use the below to change the working directory and run the php script and passing it three commands:

```
 p = subprocess.Popen(["php script.php", username, password, id], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, cwd="../temp")
    p.wait()
```

This does not run the php file though and the error is it does not recognise this as an internal or external command.

Is this the right way to do this, should this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example tries to execute a file called "php script.php" (including the space). You need to separate the arg from the command:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["php", "script.php", username, password, id], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True, cwd="../temp")
```